# Enabling Java REST Client logging in Elasticsearch in Curl format

Tags: java, elasticsearch, curl, log4j

I'm using org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient to run queries.

According to the official documentation, it's possible to log requests in curl format:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/current/java-rest-low-usage-logging.html

I have added the following line to my log4j.properties:

```
log4j.logger.org.elasticsearch.client = debug
```

Now I see http requests, but, how can I set curl formatting?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to their documentation, you need to enable specific `tracer` logger, that is responsible specifically for curl format response.

You could achieve this in **log4j 1.x** with following lines:

```
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}] [%-5p] %c{1}:%L - %m%n

log4j.logger.tracer=TRACE, stdout
```

Answer (score 2):

Just in case someone doesn't want to bother oneself with loggers, it's possible to call `toString()` on `QueryBuilder` and see a request.

Comment: If you have already a request with multiple QueryBuilders, `request.source().toString()` gives you the whole query.

Answer (score 0):

To enable trace for RestHighLevelClient 7.+ version to show url for rest calls made by elastic client. Do below steps

1. Add dependencies (in pom if maven based)
   slf4j-api , slf4j-log4j12, jcl-over-slf4j : slf4j to make log4j work with commons logging used by elastic
   logback-classic : commons logging used by elastic
   log4j-core , log4j-api : log4j2 dependencies
2. Enable tracer in log4j properties 
   log4j.logger.tracer=TRACE, stdout

File level changes
Add these dependencies in pom.xml

```
<!-- log4j2 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- slf4j to make log4j work with commons logging used by elastic -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.12</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- To bind log4j2 to sl4j -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- To bind commons logging used by elastic to sl4j -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.12</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- commons logging used by elastic -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.3</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <!-- Defined below -->
                    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
```

Changes in log4j2.properties file

```
status = error
name = PropertiesConfig
filters = threshold
filter.threshold.type = ThresholdFilter
filter.threshold.level = debug
appenders = console
appender.console.type = Console
appender.console.name = STDOUT
appender.console.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.console.layout.pattern = %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
rootLogger.level = debug
rootLogger.appenderRefs = stdout
rootLogger.appenderRef.stdout.ref = STDOUT
log4j.logger.tracer=TRACE, stdout
```

Answer (score 0):

For **log4j version 2.x**, add following configuration in **log4j2.properties** file.

```
# Debugging elasticsearch client
loggers=esclient, esclientsniffer, tracer

logger.esclient.name = org.elasticsearch.client
logger.esclient.level = trace
logger.esclient.appenderRefs = stdout
logger.esclient.appenderRef.stdout.ref = STDOUT

logger.esclientsniffer.name = org.elasticsearch.client.sniffer
logger.esclientsniffer.level = trace
logger.esclientsniffer.appenderRefs = stdout
logger.esclientsniffer.appenderRef.stdout.ref = STDOUT

logger.tracer.name=tracer
logger.tracer.level=trace
logger.tracer.appenderRefs = stdout
logger.tracer.appenderRef.stdout.ref = STDOUT
```